# Hyperledger fabric 1.4 Error on Instantiate chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

Setting up Built Your First Network (BYFN), after creating and joining Channel, chaincode is installed on both organization peers using following cli  command -

```
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/
```

**Chaincode Installation is successful**.

While I tried to **Instantiate chaincode** from the CLI using following command   [given by HLF document.](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html)

The following error occurred while Instantiate the chaincode in Hyperledger fabric v 1.4.

```
root@8804d95b7083:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}' -P "AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"
Error: must supply value for chaincode name parameter
Usage:
  peer chaincode instantiate [flags]

Flags:
  -C, --channelID string               The channel on which this command should be executed
      --collections-config string      The fully qualified path to the collection JSON file including the file name
```

Is there any alternative way to resolve this error other than re-setup the Network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conflict with the CLI command there. You used go cli command for installing the chaincode and NodeJS cli command for instantiating the chaincode.

Comment: same error occurred from the go as well. I have edited the question again. Please see it.

Comment: The command looks fine now. It shouldn't have got the same error like before. You have passed the chaincode named parameter there with **-n mycc** and other parameters too which was not there before. It might be that you have written incorrectly while executing the command on CLI? Otherwise I don’t see any problem in your command.

Comment: I solved this by setting the #CHANNEL_NAME  in Environment variable.
So, the Required  Environment variable must be checked before running peer commad in Hyperledger Fabric Network Setup.